# how can i use nodejs with my angular project?

Tags: node.js, angular

I dont even know where to start, where to put backend files like server.js file in my angular project, how can i live reload both the server and my angular frontend? What are the best practices for this? It just an empty angular project.

I just want to make some get requests in angular from my backend with hardcoded data.

Comment: Searching for tutorials, courses or example apps is a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create your backend projet. I assume you have already installed node js.

```
0- Install nodemon by typing 'npm install -g nodemon'. It is a tool that helps develop Node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected.
1- First open your backend folder, open the cmd and then type 'npm init -y'. This command initialize a new Node.js project by running the previous command.
2- Install Express by running the following command: 'npm i express'. 
By using Express, you can quickly create server-side applications and APIs with less code and overhead
3- Create a file called index.js and open it.
This is an example of express server 

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const books = [
  { title: 'Book 1', author: 'Author 1' },
  { title: 'Book 2', author: 'Author 2' },
  { title: 'Book 3', author: 'Author 3' }
];

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send({'data': books})
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

4- Open your package.json file and then add these lines:
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "dev": "nodemon index.js"
},

5- Leave the terminal open then go to your browser and type http://localhost:3000/books et voila. You will see the list of books.

6- Create the frontend folder, open the terminal and  type 'npm init -y' to initialize the project. (I assumed that you've installed angular CLI).

7- Type this command 'ng new my-angular-app' to generate an angular project and leave everything as default.

8- Create a new Angular service by running the following command in my-angular-app directory: ng generate service book

9- Open the src/app/book.service.ts file and update it with the following code:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/books';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getBooks(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}

10- Open the src/app/app.component.ts file and update it with the following code:
and add this snippet

 books: any[];

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(books => {
      this.books = books;
    });
  }

Here, we inject the BookService into the AppComponent and call the getBooks() method in the ngOnInit() lifecycle hook to retrieve the list of books and assign it to the books property.

11- Finally, run the Angular development server using the following command:
ng serve

12- Open the browser and let the magic work.

I hope this little tutorial might help you. My recommendation is to learn how to split your code into small chunks and read some articles about what the project structure could be. Learn basic concepts such as error handling, connecting to external databases, middleware, and more (Backend).

In frontend part you have to : 
- Practice by building small projects, gradually increasing complexity, and applying different Angular features like components life cycle, services, routing, and forms.
- Engage with the Angular community by joining forums, attending webinars, and reading articles/blogs to stay updated on best practices, patterns, and emerging trends.

I know this is a long comment and i hope it motivates you. Don't be afraid to ask questions because it is a good way to learn. Happy coding.
```